# How to update an npm transitive dependency in a React project

Tags: npm, package, dependencies

I am facing an issue npm with transitive dependencies in my React project while running Blackduck scan. Few packages are showing vulnerable and needs to be upgraded. I tried a few options like updating the parent package, installing the latest version of the vulnerable package etc, but still the dependency is not getting updated. For example in the below scenario, y18n is  vulnerable dependency, I am not able to update it even if I try updating the top level package commitlint/cli, then yargs  or even installing the latest of same y18n package. Can anyone please advise, it would be of great help.

```
+-- @commitlint/cli@11.0.0
| `-- yargs@15.4.1
|   `-- y18n@4.0.1
+-- jest@25.5.4
| `-- jest-cli@25.5.4
|   `-- yargs@15.4.1
|     `-- y18n@4.0.1
+-- next@9.5.3
| `-- webpack@4.44.1
|   `-- terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.5
|     `-- cacache@12.0.4
|       `-- y18n@4.0.1
+-- react-scripts@3.4.4
| +-- jest@24.9.0
| | `-- jest-cli@24.9.0
| |   +-- @jest/core@24.9.0
| |   | `-- jest-runtime@24.9.0
| |   |   `-- yargs@13.3.2
| |   |     `-- y18n@4.0.1
| |   `-- yargs@13.3.2
| |     `-- y18n@4.0.1
| +-- webpack@4.42.0
| | `-- terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.5
| |   `-- cacache@12.0.4
| |     `-- y18n@4.0.1
| `-- webpack-dev-server@3.11.0
|   `-- yargs@13.3.2
|     `-- y18n@4.0.1
```

Comment: aren't there any one who can help me with this?

Comment: Hi, what you have given is the dependency tree. But what you actually need to look at is the exact version of yarn is being used in your project. For that, look in your yarn.lock file. Paste the version of y18n that is being used here. Then I can suggest you some workaround

Comment: @CV - I tried replacing the same in package.lock as I am using npm, but still after the next npm install it will be overwritten by the same old previous version

Comment: Is the version 4.0.1 being flagged vulnerable or some previous version? Can you please copy paste the package information for y18n from package.lock file here?

Comment: @CV - yes this version 4.0.1 is vulnerable